# Draw using an existing figure object/canvas in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to animate a clock hand's movement using MATLAB. I created 'draw_clock()' program/script in a file named 'draw_clock.m' that goes something like this.

```
function draw_clock()
    set_figure();
    draw_clock_hands();
end

function set_figure()
    figure;
    hold on;
    axis off;
    title('Clock');
end
```

Then I have a script file named 'animate_clock.m' that has something like this:

```
hours = 0:12;
minutes = 0:59;
for i = 1:numel(hours)
    for j = 1:numel(minutes)
        draw_clock();
        pause(0.05);
        refresh;
    end
end
```

When I run 'animate_clock.m', new window/clock figure for every frame is opened instead of redrawing on the same canvas/figure. I understand why this is happening because 'set_figure()' is being called every time 'draw_clock()' is called. I'm new to MATLAB, so if there's a way to stop creating new figure with the code skeleton above. I guess if I can detect if there's a figure object already opened, then I can skip calling 'set_figure()' inside 'draw_clock()' next time it is being called?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Look at the documentation for [`figure`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html), specifically the output syntax. If you declare an output to your `figure` call it will return a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) that you can pass to other functions in your code and use with commands that allow you to specify the `Parent` property. The same is true for any command that creates an object, like `axes` and `plot`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will learn how to pass around the function handle to draw/redraw figures. :)

Answer (score 0):

So after searching and reading the doc a bit, I think there are a couple of different ways to detect if a matlab figure already exists. One that I found useful (and relatively simple) is to:
 - assign the 'Name' property to the figure window
 - find if an object with the assigned name exists using 'findobj(...)' method
 - if figure already exists, use 'hold on' to reuse the old figure
 - else, create a new figure with the name 'figure('Name', 'foo figure')'

For my case, 'set_figure()' method will become something like this:

```
function set_figure()
    fig_name = 'My Clock';
    if isempty(findobj('Name', fig_name))
        figure('Name', fig_name);
    end

    hold on;
    axis off;
end
```

Hope someone can come and improve it to become more robust. :)

Comment: Also, note that 'findobj(...)' isn't the most efficient thing to run over many iterations. In my case, it slowed down the animation after a few hundred frames (I realized that from profiling analysis). It might be better to just use '~ishandle(<figure_handle_number>)' or something else.